# How to stop Create Calendar Event function from duplicating events in my Google Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have had success using this code to generate events and it has been really great. However, I have to always query event information into a separate spreadsheet in order to use the code while avoiding duplicating of other events.

Here is my code:

```
 function create_Events(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Planner");
  var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var data = sheet.getRange("F6:T26" + last_row).getValues();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("");
  //Logger.log(data);

  for(var i = 0;i< data.length;i++){
    //index 0 =
    var event = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("").createEvent(data[i][0],
    new Date(data[i][9]),
    new Date(data[i][10]),
    {location: data[i][5],
     description: data[i][11]});
 Logger.log('Events Have Been Added To The Calendar ' + event.getId());

    
  }

}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `avoiding duplicating` you are thinking. `avoiding duplicating` you are thinking is the event title? Or, it's the start date? Or it's the end date? Or it's other parameters?

Comment: The problem is that all parameters are duplicated into the google calendar.  @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from `The problem is that all parameters are duplicated into the google calendar.`, I cannot understand `all parameters` you are thinking. Can I ask you about the detail of them?